# Setting root VC programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I'm a Swift beginner, so take it easy on me. I'll be specific in my question.

I deleted the storyboard (I want to learn how to build UI programmatically using Swift).

The below code is placed in the AppDelegate.swift

I also have ViewController.swift in the project explorer.

Firstly, is there a way to use anything other then UINavigationController..? Or having a UINavigationController is a must requirement..?

If not a must, how can I just refer it to a ScrollView for example..?

2ndly, with further research into Apple's own guide, they stated I can also use  `window?.isHidden = false`... Is there a difference between using the former line, and `window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`..?

Sorry if my question doesn't make sense programmatically, like I said, I'm a beginner, but I'm determined to understand why I write the code I write or copy. 
Thank you.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { 

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController (rootViewController: ViewController())

        return true
    }

...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly, is there a way to use anything other then UINavigationController..? Or having a UINavigationController is a must requirement..?

You can use any `UIViewController` subclass as the root view controller. e.g. `UITabBarController`, `UIPageViewController`, `UIViewController`, `UITableViewController`...

> how can I just refer it to a ScrollView for example..?

You can't set a `UIScrollView` as the root view controller. You can, however, add the `UIScrollView` as a subview of the `UIWindow`. I don't recommend you to do this though, because using VCs will make your code more manageable, with different classes managing different views.

> Is there a difference between using the former line, and window?.makeKeyAndVisible()..?

Yes, if you look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621601-makekeyandvisible) of `makeKeyAndVisible`:

> This is a convenience method to show the current window and position it in front of all other windows at the same level or lower. If you only want to show the window, change its 
>   `isHidden` property to `false`.

So yeah, calling `makeKeyAndVisible` will make the window the "key window".

According to [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow/1621612-iskeywindow), key window behaves like this:

> The key window receives keyboard and other non-touch related events. Only one window at a time may be the key window.

Answer (score 3):

1. A window needs a view controller. It doesn't have to be a UINavigation Controller, but it does need to be a view controller. Not all apps start with a navigation controller. In fact, you can see this yourself by looking at the storyboard that Xcode provides for you in new projects. It's just a ViewController. Can you use a ScrollView instead? If you put the scrollview (which is a UIView) into a UIViewController, sure you can.
2. Hiding a window just makes it appear and disappear. Making it the key window means that it will be the window that receives events. You might not think that it is important in iOS apps, but iOS apps can have more than one window. In the case of starting an application, it's a good idea to define the window that will be visible and be key, not just the one that will be visible.